# php i want add n

Tags: php

";
echo "My house is " . $COLOR . "
";
echo "My boat is " . $coLOR . "
";



echo "My car is " . $color . "
";
echo "My house is " . $COLOR . "
";
echo "My boat is " . $coLOR . "
";
?>

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: Reaper  check answers

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on the below code, it may help you.

```
 $values =  array (array ("item_id" =>13 ,"item_qty" => 3 ) , array ( "item_id" => 10 , "item_qty" => 7 ) , array ( "item_id" => 13 , "item_qty"=> 2 ) , array ( "item_id" => 10 , "item_qty" => 4 ) , array ( "item_id" => 10 , "item_qty" => 4 ) );
  $new_array = array();
  foreach($values as $single)
  {
    if(array_key_exists($single['item_id'],$new_array))
    {
       $new_array[$single['item_id']] += $single['item_qty'];
    }
    else
    {
    $new_array[$single['item_id']] =  $single['item_qty'];
    }
  }
  print_r($new_array);
```

This will give you the result like

```
Array ( [13] => 5 [10] => 15 )
```

item id 13 = quantity 5 and item id 10 = quantity 15

Answer (score 0):

Add the ID to an array and then increment the QTY:

```
 foreach($arr as $Item){
    $ItemID = $Item['item_id'];
    $ItemQTY = $Item['item_qty'];       
    if(!isset($Result[$ItemID])){
        $Result[$ItemID] = 0;
    }
    $Result[$ItemID] += $ItemQTY;
  }
  print_r($Result);
```